# How to update Apache Ant v1.8 to v1.9 on a Mac

Tags: java, apache, cordova, ant

I have a problem with my PhoneGap Android version and found a solution at Stackoverflow here

Problem is I have no clue how to update the Apache Ant version (on my Mac), is it possible to do that with the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Ant is nothing but an exploded binary package. All you need to do is download the desired version of Ant and explode the binary and copy over the files to your existing Ant Home folder. If you are unable to find the right documentation to update Ant on a Mac OS, I would do this if I were you ..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you describe how I "explode" a binary and where I can find my Ant version on my Mac? Thank you very much

Comment: What i meant by explode is just unzip the binary and copy over the contents to your current ANT_HOME folder ; You can open a command prompt and type ant --version provided you have ANT_HOME configured as a system variable with the right path to the installation directory

Comment: thank you. when I enter `ant --version` it (the terminal) says that my `JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly`..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a solution by setting my JAVA_HOME variable to version 1.6 instead of 1.8 (without updating my ANT_HOME variable).